# Back to basics - idiomatic way to copy string to static array

Tags: c++, c, printf

Ok, `strncpy` is not designed to work with NULL terminated strings - it's not designed for NULL terminated strings (if dest is too short it won't be terminated by NULL and if dest is longer it will be padded by zero's).

So, here is a trivial code:

```
const char *src = ....; // NULL terminated string of unknown length
char dest[30];
```

How to *src* to *dest*? `strcpy` is not safe, `strncpy` is bad choice too. So I left with *strlen* followed by `memcpy`? 
I suppose solution will differ a bit whenever I care care *dest* won't be truncated (*dest* is smaller than length of *src*) or not.

**Some limitations:**

- Legacy code, so I don't want and can not to change it to std::string
- I don't have `strlcpy` - gcc doesn't supply it.
- Code may be used in parts of application where performance is critical (e.g. I don't want to wast CPU time padding with zeros *dest* as `strncpy` does). However, I'm not talking about premature optimization, but rather the idiotic way to perform string copying in C-way.

**Edit**

Oopps, I meant `strncpy` and not `snprintf`. My mistake

Comment: Put `dest[29]=0`, use snprintf with n = 29, and don't worry about the padding.

Comment: why is `snprintf` a bad choice?

Comment: You are simply wrong in your premises. `snprintf` **always null terminates** and **never pads**.

Comment: That's not a good reason to -1 the question IMO.

Comment: If this is for an optimisation, do make sure you benchmark afterwards - seemingly wasteful functionality may sometimes still come out faster due to carefully using faster CPU instructions, better inlining etc..  Results may vary with string length, initial alignment etc..

Comment: Is it wrong to -1 questions that state false premises as fact? What should I do instead? Edit the question to add a note to the beginning that it's based on false premises?

Answer (score 4):

With [strncpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncpy/):

```
strncpy(dest, src, sizeof(dest) - 1);
dest[sizeof(dest) - 1] = '\0';
```

This pads with zeros, but does much less formatting work than `snprintf`. If you really must have the computer do as little as possible, describe it yourself:

```
char* last = dest + sizeof(dest) - 1;
char* curr = dest; /* assuming we must not alter 'dest' */
while (curr != last && *src) { *curr++ = *src++; }
*last = '\0'; /* avoids a branch, but always writes.
If branch prediction is working well and the text normally fits:
if (curr == last) { *curr = '\0'; } */
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you're talking about `strncpy()`, which might not terminate the string and will fill the remainder of the buffer with zeros.

`snprintf()` always terminates the destination string (as long as thebuffer has a size of at least 1) and doesn't pad the remainder of the buffer with zeros.

In summary, `snprintf()` *is* what you want, except you're very concerned about performance.  Since `snprintf()` needs to interpret the format string (even if all it ends up doing is copying a string), you might be better off with something like `strlcpy()` for bounded string copy operations.

(and if you want `strlcpy()` but don't have it, you can get the rather simple [source here](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/~checkout~/src/lib/libc/string/strlcpy.c?content-type=text%2Fplain). For completeness, `strlcat()` [is here](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/~checkout~/src/lib/libc/string/strlcat.c?content-type=text%2Fplain))

Comment: +1 for reading OP's mind and figuring out the mistake in the question

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care about truncation, you can use `strncat()`:

```
dest[0] = 0;
strncat(dest, src, sizeof dest - 1);
```

Comment: Making the string empty and concatenating with `strcat()` is the other way to ensure that there is a null terminator at the end. This also avoids padding. Seems like backwards thinking, though. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd just roll my own:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(dest) - 1) && src[i] != NULL; i++)
{
    dest[i] = src[i];
}
dest[i] = NULL;
```

This ensures that `dest` is null-terminated, but never adds more nulls than necessary. If you're really performance-sensitive, you can declare this as a macro or an inline function in a common header.

Answer (score 1):

Use `snprintf`. It always null-terminates and does not do any null padding. Don't know where you got the misconceptions about it...

Answer (score 0):

`std::copy(src, src+strlen(src)+1, dest)`

Comment: Shouldn't be using C-strings anyway.

Comment: that's a little simplistic; I've seen enough of your posts to know you know it too ;-P.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question entirely, but if you're concerned about zero-padding it can often be done pretty efficiently if you initialize your array like this.

```
char dest[30] = { 0 };
```

If you initialize it like that you don't have to care about extra logic to add '\0' to the end of the string and it might even turn out faster.

But if you're going to optimize remember to measure the performance before and after the optimization. Otherwise always code with readability and maintainability in mind.

Comment: I don't think that you need C99 for this. Initializers are part of C89, too. Not part of C89 are *designate initializers* where you would write something like 'char dest[30] { [29] = 0 };`

Comment: @Jens I stand corrected. I will edit my answer. Anyway, you shouldn't have to consider older standards than C99 anyway.